# Patchvalue angular 6 not working

Tags: angular, forms, angular6

When i try patchValue it does not work at all. Also no errors.

```
@ViewChild('sForm') serviceplanForm: NgForm;

objectid = '';
allisloaded = true;
edit = false;

constructor(private service: GeneralService,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.objectid = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

  if (Object.keys(params).length !== 0 && params.constructor === Object) {
    this.edit = true;
    this.allisloaded = true;
    this.setFields(params);
  }
});
}
private setFields(params: any) {
 this.serviceplanForm.form.patchValue({
   objectname: 'asdfsdf'
 });
}
```

The html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(sForm)" #sForm="ngForm">

    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!objectname.valid && sForm.submitted)}">
      <label>{{ 'serviceplan.NAME' | translate }} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel #objectname="ngModel" name="objectname" required>
      <span *ngIf="!objectname.valid && sForm.submitted" class="help-block text-danger">{{ 'serviceplane.SERVICEPLANNAMEREQUIRED' | translate }}</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

The same code will work in other modules that i have but for some reason it does not work in this component.

the form is showing up correctly when i log the serviceplanForm.

## UPDATE

Ok when i call the patchvalue inside a httpcall it suddenly works.
But i don't want this.

```
this.service.callService(new 
Method(environment.api.methods.objects.getOne  + this.objectid , null, 'get')).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.serviceplanForm.form.patchValue({
      objectname: 'testname'
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to call updateValueAndValidity method on form?

Comment: Yes but no change

Comment: Check that you're goign through the `setField` method with a console log.

Comment: @trichetriche how do i dot that?

Comment: `console.log('hey')` in your function ?

Comment: @trichetriche yes the method is being executed but the values ar not changing

Comment: You did like this `serviceplanForm: NgForm` which is template driven form, but `patchValue()` is for `Reactive forms`

Comment: @Soner_Altın you can try the `setValue()`.

Comment: patchValue does not through errors. If you want to check for errors, try using setValue.

Comment: there could also be an issue of the context that `this` is referring to, may try posting a stackBlitz of your code snippet so that we can play with it to find the issue